# finding building name from google map api

Tags: python, django, google-maps

I am working on a django project and using google maps api, when I am placing the bubble on a monument say "Taj mahal" it gives me address of that locality and it does not tell me the name of the monument that its taj mahal.

latitude and longitude of Taj Mahal is : 27.1750° N, 78.0419° E

this gives me address "Dashehara Ghat Road, Dharmapuri, Forest Colony, Tajganj, Agra, Uttar Pradesh 282006, India"
but their is no way to find that its Taj Mahal.

I am using this api :http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=27.1750,78.0419&sensor=true

can we find the name of the monument or building based on its latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 0):

Tried the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/)?...

Comment: I will try and will let you know.